# Differences between firefox, Ie and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

My site is displaying differently in Chrome to other browsers. I have checked in IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome. All are ok apart from Chrome.

Looking at the CSS im not sure what the problem is.

Its 3 equal sized boxes in a line next to each other. the left and middle box are aligned but the right box is 20px higher up in Chrome.

Here is the CSS for the boxes:

```
#home_boxes {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    clear: both;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#home_boxes p {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#home_boxes h2 {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        font-size: 14pt;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }

#home_boxes .box_content {
        width: 220px;
        float: right;
        padding: 5px;
    }

#contact_box {
    width: 318px;
    min-height: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../images/3box/contact.png') no-repeat #efefef;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}

#contact_box:hover {
    background: url('../images/3box/contact-hover.png') no-repeat #00529f;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    color: #fff;
}

#about_box {
    width: 318px;
    min-height: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../images/3box/about.png') no-repeat #efefef;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}

#about_box:hover {
    background: url('../images/3box/about-hover.png') no-repeat #00529f;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    color: #fff;
}

#home_boxes #side_newsletter_box {
    width: 320px;
    background: url('../images/3box/newsletter.png') no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}

#newsletter_box {
    width: 318px;
    min-height: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../images/3box/newsletter.png') no-repeat #efefef;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}


#newsletter_box:hover {
    background: url('../images/3box/newsletter-hover.png') no-repeat #00529f;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    color: #fff;
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
    <div id = "home_boxes">

        <div id="newsletter_box">
            <div class = "box_content">
                <h2><?=get_content(610)?></h2>
                <p><?=get_content(3234)?></p>
                <form action = <?=$myroot?>"newsletter_process.php" method = "post">
                    <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "news_signup_input" value = <?=get_content(27)?> onClick = "this.value=''" />
                    <input type = "submit" name = "newsletter_submit" value = "" class = "news_signup_submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <a href = "contact">
    <div id = "contact_box">
        <div class = "box_content">
            <h2><?=get_content(1641)?></h2>
            <p><?=get_content(3257)?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>

    <a href = "about">
    <div id = "about_box">
        <div class = "box_content">
            <h2><?=get_content(3236)?></h2>
            <p><?=get_content(3749)?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Can someone see a problem. As im not sure of what the problem is i've been messing around with the CSS for a while but to no avail. I did not create this code, i've taken it on from someone else.

Comment: I think If it worked for IE, Firefox, Safari then it may not have problem for chrome have you tried clear cahe?

Comment: Unable to replicate the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/BSBSy/

Comment: yes i've tried clearing cache (ctrl + f5) and it did nothing

Comment: ive already cleared cash. anybody have some sort of solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as im aware its simple, Place a `clear` beneath the 3 box divs (`newsletter_bos`, `contact_box`, `about_box`) but within the `main` (`home_boxes`) div.

something like this

```
.clear {
clear: both;
line-height: 0%;
height: 0px;
display: block;
}
```

This should solve your problem and align all boxes correctly.